# Moving a single item to right side of navbar (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to move a single `nav-item` to the right side of the navbar but it doesn't work. I'm using a simple `navbar`, with no search tool or dropdown menu, as the below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <!-- This is the item I want to move to the left -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

- I've tried using `justify-content-end` only on the `nav-item` but got no result
- I've tried using `ms-auto` on the `ul` but it moved the whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to Fix](https://codepen.io/tylerbryceobier/pen/eYjpJRQ)     You are missing the closing ul tag. Also make another ul with that link li and li item and apply the ms-auto on that ul tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <!-- This is the item I want to move to the left -->

        </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="bg-primary">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! About the <ul>, I just edited the question. I tried to simplify the code before posting it haha

Comment: @Rod You are more than welcome. I understand, im glad that it is working for you! Happy Holidays, good luck on your project.